# SELECT with INNER JOIN (or other) setting value for result that is not in the second table

Tags: sql, select, firebird

I have no idea how to do this with SQL (Firebird 2.5).

I have two tables. In the first table I have a list with the product information and in the second table I have the orders that use, by relationship with primary keys, the products of the first table.

I need to select all the items in the product table and take the sum of the entire quantity of products used in the order table. If the product was not used in any order, I still need the product listed, with a sum equal to zero.

Comment: This question shows a severe lack of research.

Comment: Excuse me for asking this question. I'm new to SQL, I've been searching for 3 days searching on google, here on Satckoverflow and other forums. I really just asked the question for not being able to find an answer that would lead me to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  left join  and coalesce eg:

```
 select table1.product , coalesce(sum(table2.quantity) ,0)
 from table1 
 left  join  table2 on table1.col1key = table2.col2key
 group by table1.product
```

Comment: AFAIK , the coalesce is not necessary

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, if it's not necessary, what do you recommends?

Comment: scaisEdge, Thanks! It Works!

Comment: @ThiagoMedeiros Just use `sum(table2.quantity)` without the coalesce.

Comment: I have added  the coalesce because the OP esplictally require 0 id sum is null .. anyway  .. is not the main part of the problem